# Laravel belongsTo returns, put can't save in var

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get the username by a item with belongsTo.

I have this in my Item model:

```
public function user()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

And this in my controller:

`$user = $item->user->username;`

But I get:

`Trying to get property of non-object`

And when I do:

`return $item->user->username;`

In my controller it works.

What can be wrong?

Controller/Model: http://pastebin.com/qpAh8eFd

Comment: http://pastebin.com/qpAh8eFd

Comment: I suppose you get the error from the view, right? then show the view as well. Otherwise there is nothing wrong (apart from missing '$' in the constructor, but that's a type in the paste?), and apparently you don't have related record in the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have following function in your controller:

```
public function index($type)
{
    $items = $this->item->where('type', '=', $type)->get();
    foreach($items as $item):
        $user = $item->user->username;
    endforeach;
    return View::make('items.index', ['items' => $items, 'user' => $user]);
}
```

You don't need to do a `foreach` look in the controller and whatever you are doing you are doing it wrong, instead make your `index` function like this:

```
public function index($type)
{
    $items = $this->item->where('type', '=', $type)->get();
    return View::make('items.index', ['items' => $items]);
}
```

Pass only `$items` to your `items/index.blade.php` view. You may do a `foreach` loop in your view if needed and within each iteration you may access the `user` related to the `item` using something like this:

```
@foreach($items as $item)
    {{ $item->user->uername }}
@endforeach
```

You may get `Trying to get property of non-object` error message because each `$item` may don't have a related user. So, make sure each `$item` has a related user. You can also, use following to get items with `user`:

```
$items = $this->item->with('user')->where('type', '=', $type)->get();
return View::make('items.index', ['items' => $items]);
```

In your view you may check if the item has a related user:

```
@foreach($items as $item)
    @if($item->user)
        {{ $item->user->uername }}
    @endif
@endforeach
```